# How do I run an embedded JQ script in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looks like something is wrong with my code? HTML won't run it. When I click the button element in HTML the font size does not change. What am I missing?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").css("font-size", "5em");
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't give a `<script>` tag *both* a `src` and content. It's one or the other.

You need this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").css("font-size", "5em");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it suppose to look like this?

Comment: @sean Yes, as I said in my answer.

Comment: One more question:

Thank you. Last question on this topic: I am trying to add this to an external file. Is this correct? If not what is the correct way?

My HTML file:

~<head>script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fitness.js"></script>
</head>

My external JQ file:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("button").hide();
    })
  });

Comment: I also added a cleaner version in your previous comment with example to me